# For $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, prove if $A$ or $B$ is open, then $A+B = \{x+y: x\in A, y\in B\}$ is open.

Tags: real-analysis

For $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, prove if $A$ or $B$ is open, then $A+B = \{x+y: x\in A, y\in B\}$ is open.

Note: Without loss of generality, from here on, I'll let $A$ be open.

---

This proof has been completed in other posts on the site by noting that $(1)$ a point $y \in \mathbb{R}^d$ added to an open set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is an open set and $(2)$, that

$$A + B = \bigcup_{y \in B} \left(A+ y \right)$$

is a union of open sets. From there it follows that $A+B$ is open.

Now, this second part I get, and can take for granted at this point. But the first part, the "translation" property, I'm having a tough time showing for some reason.

My thinking is as follows: in order to show that the set $A + y$ is open, for some point $y$, we need to show that for arbitrary $x \in A$ that there exists an open ball $Z_r$ such that $Z_r(x+y) \subset A + y$ for some $r>0$.

Since we're given that $A$ is open, we know that for all $x \in A$ there exists an open ball in $A$ such that for all $x'$ in that ball that $|x' - x| < r_x$. Adding $y$ to that ball results in $x' \mapsto (x' + y)$ and $x \mapsto (x + y)$. Clearly, the distance between these mapped points is unaffected, and since $x',x \in A$, then $(x' + y), (x+y) \in \left(A+y\right)$ so we can take $r$ for our open ball $Z_r$ to be $r_x$ and see that $Z_r \subset \left(A+y\right)$. QED.

That just seems to long, for something so simple (if it's even correct).

Comment: It seems OK to me, and isn't *that* long.

Comment: That's hardly long at all! It's how I'd do it.

Answer (score 1):

The map $x \to x+y$ is easily seen to be a homeomorphism with inverse map $x \to x-y$. $A+y$ is the image of $A$ under this homeomorphism, so it is open.